# Attributes not displaying in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, variables, attributes, woocommerce

At my first product page, when I go to Product Data, select “Variable product” and then click on “Variations” I get the message, “**Before adding variations, add and save some attributes on the Attributes tab**.”
[image]

So… I went to the Attributes tab, created an attribute titled ‘Colors’, and one titled ‘Size’. Then for terms on dimensions I added “Black, Blue, Red White” and for Size, I added he terms, “S, M, L, Xl”
[image]

With those saved, I went back to my saved product, went back to “Product Data”, selected “Variable product” and clicked on, “Variations”

But there I again see that message "**Before adding variations, add and save some attributes on the Attributes tab.**".

Comment: are you tried by deactivating all plugins except woocommerce?

Comment: You're adding these to the attributes tab that's directly above the variations tab?

Comment: The attribute tab that is above variations is empty. Nothing is displaying here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now working fine.
[image]

**Error:** "toolbar" class was taking potion fixed. It was taking this style from gravity plugin stylesheet.